Surface area of a sphere in the first octant
I am trying to solve an optional geometry problem in MIT's edx calculus course, but I can't figure out why my attempt at this problem is incorrect. The problem is:

The four-sided solid shown is the part of the solid sphere (of radius 2, centered at the origin) in the first octant. Find its total surface area.

My approach was: the total surface area of the entire sphere is $4\pi r^2$. With $r = 2$, this is $16 \pi$. By symmetry, we can find the surface area in the first octant of three-space by dividing by $8$, giving $2 \pi$.
This answer was incorrect, and I'm not sure where I went wrong.

That's the curved surface area. Did you include the flat surface area (for the other 3 sides?)

@CalvinLin I don't think I fully understand the difference. The wording in the question was confusing, as I didn't know what the "four sides" of the sphere were.

@JohnT As the sphere is solid, its surface in the first octant is made of 4 pieces: what you calculated and the intersections with the other planes, which gives you three quarters of circle extra.

Think of it this way. Cut a (perfectly round) orange (centered at the origin) into eighths, slicing along the coordinate planes. Take one of your chunks. What is the surface of that chunk?

@Valere I'm having difficulty visualizing this. Do you know of any graphing software I can use to plot this?

Stole this picture from a quick google search:

You have a correct approach: The total surface area of the solid sphere is $16\pi$. As hopefully emphasized in the image above, when we consider an octant of a solid sphere, we are imagining "slicing" the solid sphere into 8 symmetrical pieces by the x,y, and z axes. This "slicing" now creates a new shape, namely the blue shape above, which has four faces, as the comments noted:

The curved face
The flat face along the xy-plane
The flat face along the xz-plane
The flat face along the yz-plane

So when we divide the total surface area by 8, and get $2\pi$, this is only the surface area of the curved face! We still have three more faces to consider in order to get the total surface area of the octant.
Let's find the surface area of one of these three flat faces. Note that each of these flat faces has the same surface area due to symmetry, so once we find one, we have them all!
Now, since we arrived here after cutting a sphere symmetrically into 8 sections, you should convince yourself that each of these flat faces is in fact a quarter of a circle with radius 2. Thus, to find the surface area, we can consider the equation for the area of a circle:
$$A_{\circ}=\pi r^2$$
and divide by 4 for the quarter we're interested in:
$$A_{*}=\frac{\pi r^2}{4}$$.
Therefore, we have that the surface area of one of these faces is:
$$A_{*}=\frac{\pi r^2}{4}=\frac{\pi \times 2^2}{4}=\pi$$
And now we are done. The surface area of the curved face is $2\pi$, and the surface area of the other three faces are each $\pi$, so we get:
$$A_{octant}=2\pi + 3\pi=5\pi$$

The word “sphere” by itself means a surface. That is, a sphere is hollow. “Solid sphere” implies that the interior of the sphere is part of the object.
A “solid sphere” is usually called a ball.
The ball of radius $2$ centered at the origin consists of all points $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy
$$ x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 4. $$
Note that this formula has $\leq$ where the formula for a sphere has $=.$
The object described in this problem isn’t just a one-eighth piece of a sphere. A one-eighth piece of a sphere is just a surface that cannot contain anything.
But the object in this problem includes all points between that piece of the sphere and the three coordinate planes.
To visualize this properly, as already suggested in a comment you just need a knife and a ball-shaped object that you can cut with that knife. Cut the ball in half, then cut one half in half again to get quarters, then cut a quarter in half. Each cut creates new surface area from the interior of the ball.
You are asked for all the surface area of the remaining piece of the ball, including both the original surface and the new surfaces created by cutting.
